# Dynamics CRM 4.0 Picklist Mapping

Tags: dynamics-crm-4, crm

I have been asked to make some customisation changes to our Dynamics CRM 4.0 system and I am struggling with a key part of the changes.

There is a picklist called "CompanyType" defined on the Companies entity and I need to display the selected value of this Picklist on the Opportunity entity's data entry form in a read-only state.

There is a predefined system 1:N relationship between Company and Opportunity called "Potential Customer".

I have researched this for some time and I have followed the following steps so far:

1. I created an identical attribute called "RelatedCompanyType" on the Opportunity entity,  making sure that all it's picklist values matched those of the "CompanyType" picklist.
2. I added a new mapping to the existing "Potential Customer" relationship,  mapping the picklist attribute "CompanyType" to the picklist attribute "RelatedCompanyType".
3. I Saved and published bothe the Company and Opportunity entities.

Having done this the value still does not map and the picklist on the Opportunity, whether new or existing, remains blank despite a value being set on the Company.

I have been through the mappings again to make sure this attribute is not mapped twice and now I am at a loss.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris, I followed your steps exactly and everything perfectly works.
To be honest I followed your steps except that the Picklists have the same physical name in both sides.

(Maybe this is silly but), After creating a new Company record and selecting a value from the Picklist, create a new opportunity from the left side (Related Opportunity), then you'll see that the other Picklist will be automatically mapped the Company's Picklist.

Comment: Thank you very much Anwar.   It was what you said (Maybe this is silly but)... From the left side was the key.   Previously I had been creating the Opportunity from the sidebar on the main screen and then setting it's PotentialCustomer and clicking save.   By creating Opportunity from within the Company the mapping works!